# htaccess redirect root only without changing url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

i have 2 sites:

```
www.test1.com
```

and

```
www.test2.com
```

With the below code i can redirect from test1.com to test2.com without changing the url

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test1.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://test2.com/$1 [P]
```

But if i try to access a folder in test1 for example test1.com/folder it also redirects.
So how i can only redirect the root folder but still without changing the url but be able to access a subfolder in my main domain?

Answer (score 0):

Just change your regex to allow only landing page:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://test2.com [P]
```